# True color CImageList

Tags: c++, mfc

How do I load a true color image into a CImageList?

Right now I have

```
mImageList.Create(IDB_IMGLIST_BGTASK, 16, 1, RGB(255,0,255));
```

Where `IDB_IMGLIST_BGTASK` is a 64x16 True color image.  The ClistCtrl I am using it in shows 16 bpp color.  I don't see a Create overload that allows me to specify both the bpp and the resource to load from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Needs 4 lines of code, but this works:

```
CBitmap bm;
bm.LoadBitmap(IDB_IMGLIST_BGTASK);
mImageList.Create(16, 16, ILC_COLOR32 | ILC_MASK, 4, 4);
mImageList.Add(&bm, RGB(255,0,255));
```

Comment: Why am I always too slow or everyone else so amazingly fast? :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
CImageList::Create(int cx, int cy, UINT nFlags, int nInitial, int nGrow)
```

allows to specify different flags with the `nFlags` parameter. You can try to use something like `ILC_COLOR32 | ILC_MASK`.